# User Define Type Read Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am developing a system for a (my) small business. I have about 20 data files (Clients / suppliers / stores items / fixed assets / rentals / employees ...etc.) Each record of these files is defined using a Type statement and written or read using a Put or Get statement.
Each data file is maintained or incremented with a separate Workbook.
I also have separate workbooks to control the day to day processes of the company. (Sales / Rentals / store movement etc.) These 'operational' workbooks rely heavily on the records from the data files. They also produce further data files for daily movements.
The system is controlled by one Workbook called Menu.xlsm which allows the user to select the desired workbook. Menu.xlsm contains all the type statements, general procedures, functions and Forms. It is referenced in all other workbooks and is always open. The user is restricted to two open workbooks - Menu and one other.
The system is on a network server and written in such a way that the user can only open the workbooks 'read-only'. The user NEVER saves a workbook, they always save the data to a data file.
Basically I have a database system and am using Excel as the interface.

My Type statement is

```
Public Type CLocDesc
   Atv As String * 3
   CadName As String * 10
   CadDate As Date
   EditName As String * 10
   EditDate As Date
   Empresa As String * 10
   OSNo As Integer
   ClNo As Integer
   Fantasia As String * 30
   Cidade As String * 40
   UF As String * 2
   PedClient As String * 30
   InsCid As String * 30
   InsUF As String * 2
   DtStart As Date
   DtEnd As Date
   QtMod As Integer
   QtAr As Integer
   QtOut As Integer
   LocMods As Single
   LocAr As Single
   LocOther As Single
   LocVenc As Integer
End Type
Public CLoc As CLocDesc  ' This appears at the top of the module.
```

I know with absolute certainty that Len(CLoc) = 223
This particular file controls the company's rental contracts. We rent to our clients. I am English but have made Brazil my home. Thus some of the element names are Portuguese.
Whenever a user opens the Rental Workbook this file (Rental.rnd) is loaded automatically by a standard module procedure(LoadData()) called by workbook_open().
This is the LoadData proceedure. Some non relevant code is omitted.(Condicional load / % load indication / table sizing)

```
'                                                      LOAD  DATA  .
Sub LoadData()
Open Range("MDP") + "Rental.rnd" For Random As #1 Len = Len(Cloc)
Nitems = LOF(1) / Len(Cloc)       ' Number of records
J = 0                             ' Line counter for data table
With Range("DataTable")
   For I = 1 To Nitems
   '                      On Error Resume Next
   Get #1, I, Cloc               ' This command  : Error 59 - Bad record length.
   '                      On Error GoTo 0
   J = J + 1
   .Cells(J, 1) = I
   .Cells(J, 2) = Trim(Cloc.CadName)
   .Cells(J, 3) = Cloc.CadDate
   .Cells(J, 4) = Trim(Cloc.EditName)
   .Cells(J, 5) = Cloc.EditDate
   .Cells(J, 6) = Trim(Cloc.Atv)
   .Cells(J, 7) = Trim(Cloc.Empresa)
   .Cells(J, 8) = Cloc.OSNo
   .Cells(J, 9) = Cloc.ClNo
   .Cells(J, 10) = Trim(Cloc.Fantasia)
   .Cells(J, 11) = Trim(Cloc.Cidade)
   .Cells(J, 12) = Trim(Cloc.uf)
   .Cells(J, 13) = Trim(Cloc.PedClient)
   .Cells(J, 14) = Trim(Cloc.InsCid)
   .Cells(J, 15) = Trim(Cloc.InsUF)
   .Cells(J, 16) = Cloc.DtStart
   .Cells(J, 17) = Cloc.DtEnd
   .Cells(J, 18) = Cloc.QtMod
   .Cells(J, 19) = Cloc.QtAr
   .Cells(J, 20) = Cloc.QtOut
   .Cells(J, 21) = Cloc.LocMods         ' Bad read starts here
   .Cells(J, 22) = Cloc.LocAr
   .Cells(J, 23) = Cloc.LocOther
   .Cells(J, 24) = Cloc.LocOther + Cloc.LocAr + Cloc.LocMods
   .Cells(J, 25) = Cloc.LocVenc
   Next I
End With
Close
End Sub
```

When the error does not occur the data loads correctly.
When the error does occur I uncomment the On error commands and rerun the program. The program finishes normally and the data in the table indicates that the data has been correctly read up to Cloc. QtOut and subsequent elements not read.
It would appear that the 'Error 59 Bad record length' is a result of the 'VBA parsing code' being unable to interpret the data in bytes 210 to 213 of the CLoc buffer data read by the Get statement.
To verify this I added this code :

```
Type AllClocDesc
   StAll As String * 223
End Type
Dim AllCloc As AllClocDesc
...and ...
Get #1, I, AllCloc
```

Thus I have a 223 byte string (AllCloc.StAll) identical to the buffer read by the offending Get #1, I, Cloc. I then wrote a proccedure to parse this string and verify the data on disk. I can post the code if you wish). The data on disk is CORRECT.
If I close and reopen the workbook the error persists.

As I said above the type statement and public decalarion of CLoc is in Menu.xlsm. The LoadData code and hence the error producing code is in a workbook called Rentals.xlsm.
So, I close Rentals.xlsm. In Menu.xlsm i cut 'Public CLoc As CLocDesc' and paste it in a slightly different place. Then debug/compile and Save, but do not close, Menu.xlsm.
As if by magic LoadData() completes normally, with the correct data.

The saved copy of Menu.xlsm should be identical to that which just ran correctly.
Close Rental.xlsm, Close Menu.xlsm. Reopen Menu.xlsm, Reopen Rental.xlsm.
FAIL !!  Error 59 Bad record length.

I stated above that the users open the workbooks "read only", thus two users can open the workbook (almost) simultaneously. It is common for one user to receive error 59 and the other not. The same workbook and the same data!

I have around 30 random access files in all. About 10 of them have in the past or are currently giving identical problems. I have 22 workbooks totaling 4.04 MB. I have stopped adding more simply because the users are no longer able to use the system.

I have thought about using class modules for the data. But 30 class modules instead of 30 type statements. Talk about a sledgehammer to crack a nut.
When I first started I used print/write and delimiters. I gave up very quickly when the users started including comas, semicolons and quotation marks in their texts. 
I believe that Microsoft deliberately created the UDT/Get/Put for the purpose for which I am using it.

There is something very very very strange happening here.

How can I solve my problem ?

Ian Simmons

This is an update to the posts above. 
As my company has a subscription for Office 365 I decided to invoke the help of M microsoft.
The first problem was to find the registered user – who had permission to open a support ticket. It turned out to be the retailer who sold us the subscription.(Not my IT guy??). The promised 4 hour return ended up taking 3 days. Finally we had a conference call – myself / a microsoft engineer / analyst and somebody from the retailer. Both tried to explain to me that since the problem was with my code they (microsoft) were unable to help.
Ticket : SUP86188 - LATAM-BR-MSFT-O365-Solicitação Eng microsoft
To open the ticket, I had to submit details of the problem to the retailer and I included a list of the posts that I had made. The conference call failed several times, finally the microsoft engineer/analyst called me directly and admitted that after consulting the posts, he too was convinced that this was a BUG and suggested that I report it to microsoft.  I asked why HE could not report it and he replied that he was NOT ALLOWED to.
I wish I had recorded that conversation!
Later I received an email from the retailer stating that the ticket was RESOLVED and closed.
This is disgusting behaviour from a multinational. 
I have deliberately omitted names from this post - the ticket number is sufficient should anyone from microsoft be interested.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The first that I would do is download [MZ Tools](https://www.mztools.com/v8/download_trial.aspx) and goto File and click "Clean Project".  This will get rid any of trash that builds up over time caused by Excel not cleaning up the code properly.

Comment: Do all records in your data set fail, or just a few? Can you show example records in your question?

Comment: Are your data files being updated during the day, or only when users are not reading them?  (If they are being updated during the day, there is a good chance that the second half of the offending record is still in a write buffer in the memory of whichever computer is doing the updates, waiting to be committed to the disk drive when the buffer is full, and so any other computer trying to read the file is only seeing the first half of the record.)

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  @ThomasInzina - I will download MZ Tools and report results.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  @xidgel - The Get is in a loop, if fails on all iterations of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  @YowE3K - I am developing the program offline, this way there is no way your suggestion can cause the problem. Search for "UDT parsing error" on Microsoft Community, there is more information there.

Comment: "two users can open the workbook (almost) simultaneously. It is common for one user to receive error 59 and the other not." - that doesn't sound like it is being **used** offline.  Perhaps you misunderstood what I meant by "data files" - I wasn't referring to your code, I was referring to the files being used to store data, e.g. the file referred to by `Range("MDP") + "Rental.rnd"`.

Comment: I understand exactly what you meant. My program is written in such a way that I can, by changing a U: to a D: in one cell, force my development copy of the program to use data on my HD. Hence I know other users are not involved.

Comment: @ThomasInzina  I have downloaded and installed MZ Tools. I cleaned every workbook twice. No Luck! The error persists.

Comment: I'll put up a bounty for your post tomorrow.   It would help if you could prepare a workbook with moxk data amd a download link

Comment: The first and foremost problem is that people tend to use Excel as database. Thus, we get what you get now. You should move all your data into SQL Server/MySQL RDBMS. This way you can use Excel as an interface.

Comment: Why do you need `String * 30`? Just curios.

Comment: @Vityata  Fantasia is our internal name by which our client is known. The string * 30 allows for this name to have (up to) 30 characters. For example we have a client called XXX and they have installations in several cities - we use XXX city1. XXX city2 etc.

Comment: @ianSimmons - what exactly do you win by using `String * 30` instead of `String`?

Comment: Following MS reference: a "bad record length" error can occur if the variables in a `Put` statement contain variable-length strings without keeping in mind that a 
2-byte descriptor will be added (spec. variants up to 4-byte). 
So the originally calculated record length specified in the `Len` clause of the Open statement (223) may differ by 9 string values x 2 bytes from the actual size and 
an error may occur when reading the 20th type variable `.LocMods` (213 cumulated bytes + n  > 223) - cf. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/bad-record-length-error-59

Comment: I am somewhat tired of comments suggesting I look at MS Help :  a "bad record length" error can occur if the variables in a Put statement contain variable-length strings. ALL MY STRINGS are defined as fixed length (Look at the type statement - string * length)

Comment: My intention was to help, not to spell *ms help* out to you. - What about just changing the direction of deduction:  
an error 59 occured at or after the 20th type variable, so possibly *NOT* "ALL my strings" have been put according assumed type definitions at any time or anywhere, go through it :-)

Comment: @ThomasInzina. I apologise, I am a little stressed. I have 15 employees using the system and two or three times a day they appear before me reporting "Error 59 - Bad Record length". Very strange since they are all using identical read only copies of the workbook.

Comment: If I understand well reading the 223 bytes in one go is working? Couldn't you just `Lset` the 223 byte string user type to the 223 byte initial user type?

Comment: @Vityata: he gets a fixed record length if he fixes the length of the fields.  That's the win.

Answer (score 10):

Using `Open For Random` is not ideal given that it will convert the strings from BSTR/UTF16 on 2 bytes to ANSI on 1 byte with a potential loss depending on the character. That said, your issue could be due to a race condition or maybe the procedure is trying to load a corrupted or a different record.

Instead, use `Open For Binary Shared` to read/write the data without conversion and in a single call:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub MemCpy Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (dst As Any, src As Any, ByVal size As LongPtr)

Const path = "c:\temp\record.bin"

Sub AddRecord()

  ' dummy record '
  Dim record As CLocDesc
  record.Atv = "123"
  record.LocMods = 1.76

  ' to binary '
  Dim buffer() As Byte
  ReDim buffer(0 To LenB(record) - 1)
  MemCpy buffer(0), ByVal VarPtr(record), LenB(record)

  ' check file length is a multiple of the record length '
  If Len(Dir(path)) Then If FileLen(path) Mod LenB(record) Then _
    Err.Raise 5, , "Unexpected file length"

  ' to file '
  Dim f As Integer
  f = FreeFile
  Open path For Binary Shared As f
    Put f, FileLen(path) + 1, buffer
  Close

End Sub

Sub LoadRecords()

  ' check file length is a multiple of the record length '
  Dim record As CLocDesc
  If FileLen(path) Mod LenB(record) Then Err.Raise 5, , "Unexpected file length"

  ' load file to buffer '
  Dim f As Integer, p As Long, buffer() As Byte
  ReDim buffer(0 To FileLen(path) - 1)

  f = FreeFile
  Open path For Binary Shared As f
    Get f, 1, buffer
  Close

  ' to records '
  Dim records() As CLocDesc
  ReDim records(0 To FileLen(path) \ LenB(record) - 1)
  MemCpy ByVal VarPtr(records(0)), buffer(0), UBound(buffer) + 1

End Sub
```

But working with records stored directly in a file is going to be a pain to maintain since you'll have to manually update most of them if at some point you need to add a new field/column.

A better solution would be to setup a database. You could use an Access database, or a simple Excel file accessible with an [ADO connection](https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+xlsx+ado).

A simple alternative would be to use a `Recordset` to save/load the records to/from a file:

```
' Required reference: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects '

Sub UsageRecordset()
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, fields As ADODB.fields, i As Long

  ' create a recordset, define the fields and save it to a file '

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

  Set fields = rs.fields
  fields.Append "Id", adBSTR, 8
  fields.Append "Price", adDouble

  rs.Open
  rs.Save "c:\temp\records.dat"
  rs.Close

  ' add some records '

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  rs.Open "c:\temp\records.dat"

  rs.AddNew
  rs("Id").value = "kt547865"
  rs("Price").value = 4.7

  rs.AddNew
  rs("Id").value = "kt986543"
  rs("Price").value = 2.3

  rs.Save
  rs.Close

  ' read all the records to a sheet '

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  rs.Open "c:\temp\records.dat"

  rs.MoveFirst
  ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

  rs.Close

  ' iterate all the records '

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  rs.Open "c:\temp\records.dat"

  rs.MoveFirst
  For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount
    Debug.Print rs("Id").value
    Debug.Print rs("Price").value
    rs.MoveNext
  Next

  rs.Close

  ' find a specific record '

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  rs.Open "c:\temp\records.dat", LockType:=adLockReadOnly

  rs.MoveFirst
  rs.Find "[Price] < 5", , 1, 2

  If Not rs.EOF Then
    Debug.Print rs("Id").value
    Debug.Print rs("Price").value
  End If

  rs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Race condition : I used msconfig to limit windows/excel to one processor only - A little slower - but the same errors persists. Can the race condition be caused by any thing else?  Binary read, OK but how do I parse the 223 byte string in the buffer?  Database, I am studying hard, I have never used this approach before.

Comment: @ian Simmons, It's hard to say about the race condition without a reproducible example. Note that you can't parse as binary the 233 byte given that they were written with randomize. If you are willing to move to binary, you'll have to convert all the files first from randomize to binary.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "parse as binary the 233 byte given that they were written with randomize" . I defined a UDT wiith one element (AllCloc.Str) - a string of 223 bytes. I then read from disk and parsed the element in accordance with the structure of Cloc (See above). The string elements are simple Mid(String,Start,Nchar) extractions. The other values require converting the characters to Hex, endian considerations and functions of the type Hex2Int etc.

Comment: @ian Simmons, by that I mean `Open For Binary Shared / Get ` will only be able to read a file written with `Open For Binary Shared / Put`. The example I provided simply writes the memory from the UDT to a file. There's no need on your end to convert the characters to Hex or to consider the endlessness since you can directly access the fields of the UDT once loaded from the file (see `Sub LoadRecords()`).

Comment: @ian Simmons, If you can't move from Randomize, at least try `Open Range("MDP") + "Rental.rnd" For Random Shared As f Len = Len(Cloc)` 
 where  `f = FreeFile` and load all the records in an array before writing/parsing each UDT to Excel.

Comment: I think I understand where you are going. Give me time to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

@Ian Simmonds, in your question text you say you have tried this

```
Type AllClocDesc
   StAll As String * 223
End Type


Sub Test()
    '...
    Dim AllCloc As AllClocDesc
    '...and ...
    Get #1, I, AllCloc

End Sub
```

Perhaps try this with a byte array to diagnose what is happening

```
Type AllClocDesc2
   abAllBytes(0 To 222) As Byte
End Type

Sub Test2()
    Dim I, l


    'Dim AllCloc As AllClocDesc
    Dim AllCloc2 As AllClocDesc2
    '...and ...
    Get #1, I, AllCloc2


    LSet CLoc = AllCloc2

End Sub
```

[LSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/lset-statement) copies byte for byte.  You can inspect what gets copied into your multi-field type and you can inspect what is actually on disk by looking at the byte array.  Hope this helps.

Comment: The length is correct, `Open/Put` converts all the strings from UTF16 (2 bytes per character) to ANSI on a single byte per character.